# Marker click event always opens to the last pushed infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, marker

I have a json object `infoCentros` which I use to construct the map, like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < infoCentros.length; i++ ) {
    var centro = infoCentros[i];
    var lat = centro.cordenadas.lat;
    var lon = centro.cordenadas.long;
    if (lat && lon) {
        c++;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var moptions = {
            position: latlon,
            map: $project.gmap
        }
        moptions.icon = theme_uri +  '/images/marker.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(moptions);
        $project.mapMarkers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            $project.mapInfoWindow.setContent(
                '<div class="sescam-info-window">' + 
                    '<h3>' + centro.nombre + '</h3>' +
                    '<p>' + centro.lugar + '</h3>' +
                    '<p>Coordinador</p>' +
                    '<p>' + centro.coordinador.nombre + '</p>' +
                    '<p>' + centro.coordinador.email + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Responsable</p>' +
                    '<p>' + centro.responsable.nombre + '</p>' + 
                    '<p>' + centro.responsable.email + '</p>' 
                + '</div>'

            );
            $project.mapInfoWindow.open($project.gmap, marker);
        });
        $project.mapBounds.extend(latlon);
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine, but if I have 5 markers, It doesn't matter which one I click, the infowindow always corresponds to the last item (position and content),

Any idea what am I missing? I thought that passing `marker` to the addListener would Do the trick..

Comment: You need to use a closure for assigning the content to the infowindow in your event listener, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure

Comment: @duncan I don't understand, you mean using this? `infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);`

Comment: No, your call to `google.maps.event.addListener` should use an external function instead of an anonymous inline function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with third argument of google.maps.event.addListener. That anonymous function contains the variable from the parent scope which when evaluated with marker click will always take the last value assigned. Look for closure for more details. However you may able to get the desired behaviour by using "[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)" feature of javascript function prototype in below manner:

```
//inside for loop   
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', handleMarkerClick.bind(undefined, marker, i));
//other codes if any...
```

defining handleClick

```
function handleMarkerClick(marker, index) {
    if (typeof infowindow === 'undefined') {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    }
    var data = infoCentros[index]//helpful data
    //create content with dynamic data 
    infowindow.setContent("dynamic content");
    infowindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);//modify as per your requirement
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Duncan is right, he means you have to attach the listener outside of your for loop.  It's not specific to Google Maps, it's how javascript works.  Try searching for "javascript closures for loop" or visit this link - [Closures in Javascript](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/) for a simple explanation.

Comment: This should be ca comment, I think, instead of an aswer; unless you put the solving example, maybe?

Comment: I can't comment on answers until I reach 50 rep.  But you are right so I changed my answer slightly.